# Eloquent ORM - where(), how to include both parameters as table fields

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
$data = Booking::join('user', 'booking.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
            ->join('tickets', 'trail_booking.tkt_id', '=', 'tickets.id')
            ->where('trail_booking.user_id','=','tickets.user_id')
            ->paginate();
```

I am unable to get any result using the above query as the 'where' condition evaluates `'tbl_tickets.user_id'`to the value instead of table field.

Should I use whereRaw? Or is there any method to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the third parameter is expected to be a value, it will be escaped and quoted, so you should use `whereRaw` instead:

```php
$data = Booking::join('user', 'booking.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
        ->join('tickets', 'trail_booking.tkt_id', '=', 'tickets.id')
        ->whereRaw('trail_booking.user_id = tickets.user_id')
        ->paginate();
```

---

You could alternatively pass the value with `DB::raw` so it's not escaped:

```php
->where('trail_booking.user_id', DB::raw('tickets.user_id'))
```

But it's cleaner and more readable with `whereRaw` in my opinion and it does the same thing.

Comment: thank you. Got it worked with whereRaw already. So, no way to get it worked using where()?